# How to change the attributes for all objects inside a list in python(3)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and unfamiliar with manipulating python lists.  I have a list of tkinter widgets, more specifically buttons, which have been added to my list `btnList` by using:

`btnList.append(btn1)`

`btnList.append(btn2)`

Normally to change an object's attribute value (the state attribute for example) one would use:

`btn1.configure(state='disabled')`

`btn2.configure(state='disabled')`

which would set the state attribute of both buttons to disabled,

Is there a way to change attributes for all of the objects contained in the list?
for example setting the state of each button to disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop over your list:

```
for button in btnList:
    button.configure(state='disabled')
```

`button` will be assigned each button from your list in turn letting you call the `configure()` method on it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a fair number of ways to express this, including some one-liners, but I think a simple for loop is the cleanest:

```
for button in btnList:
    button.configure(state='disabled')
```