# Changing an attribute for each object in a list for python

Tags: python

I've tried to change the training number of players in a football team and spent far too long scratching my face off in frustration while trying to use a for loop to achieve this, here is all the code associated to the program (you can maybe skip it to the part where I will show the part I'm having trouble with)...

```
import random
import time
from operator import itemgetter


# class that creates each player and manipulates the data associated with the players which is first set here
class NewPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        # creates a placeholder name for the player then uses the function (create_name) within to fill with a string
        self.name = ""
        self.create_name()
        # creates the initial rating of a player between and including 10 and 20
        self.rating = random.randint(10, 20)
        # the amount of times a player has been trained, unique to each instance
        self.training_number = 0

    def train_player(self):
        # if the player gets trained they will get a random rating increase/decrease depending on chance and work level
        if -1 < self.training_number < 1:
            self.rating += random.randint(1, 5)
            # there cant be over excessive training so the more (work) training then the worse the modifier gets as it
            # takes a different route based on training_number
            self.training_number += 1
            print("Training was successful")
        # if the player gets retrained they use the following route and end up potentially worse
        elif 1 <= self.training_number < 2:
            # temporarily store the old value
            old = self.rating
            self.rating += random.randint(-2, 2)
            self.training_number += 1
            # the old value is used to compare and give the correct output, relaying the outcome
            if self.rating > old:
                print("Training was successful")
            elif self.rating == old:
                print("Nothing new was achieved in training")
            else:
                print("The training was terrible")
        # by this point the player won't receive a positive boost
        else:
            self.rating += random.randint(-5, -1)
            self.training_number += 1
            print("The player is too tired and picked up a slight injury")

    def create_name(self):
        forenames = ["Peter", "Steven", "Michael", "Ishaa", "Nikesh", "George", "Toby", "Jasdeep"]
        surnames = ["Chandler", "Evans", "Kelly", "Ward", "Heer", "Trepass", "Gardner", "Walker"]
        # randomly creates a name for a player
        self.name = random.choice(forenames) + " " + random.choice(surnames)


# class that creates opposition teams that are made up of 11 players
class NewTeam:
    def __init__(self):
        # variable that holds the team name, currently a placeholder
        self.team_name = ""
        # variable that holds how many points the team has earned this season, number value += 3 when a match is won,
        # 1 when drew and none when lost
        self.points = 0
        # variable that holds how many upgrade points the opposition earns
        self.upgrade_points = 0
        # creates the players and the team name for the opposition teams
        self.create_team()
        self.create_name()

    # adds 11 players to any team using the function
    def create_team(self):
        self.team = []
        # adds a goalkeeper to the team
        self.team.append(("goalkeeper1:", NewPlayer()))
        # adds four defenders to the team
        for i in range(1, 5):
            self.team.append(("defender" + str(i) + ":", NewPlayer()))
        # adds four midfielders to the team
        for i in range(1, 5):
            self.team.append(("midfielder" + str(i) + ":", NewPlayer()))
        # adds two attackers to the team
        for i in range(1, 3):
            self.team.append(("attacker" + str(i) + ":", NewPlayer()))

    # chooses a random name for the team
    def create_name(self):
        names = ["Birmingham City", "Barnsley", "Accrington Stanley", "Blackburn Rovers", "Blackpool", "AFC Wimbledon",
                 "Bolton Wanderers", "Bradford City", "Barnet", "Bristol City", "Burton Albion", "Bristol Rovers",
                 "Brentford", "Bury", "Cambridge United", "Brighton", "Hove Albion", "Chesterfield", "Carlisle United",
                 "Burnley", "Colchester United", "Crawley Town", "Cardiff City", "Coventry City", "Dagenham",
                 "Redbridge", "Charlton Athletic", "Crewe Alexandra", "Exeter City", "Derby County", "Doncaster Rovers",
                 "Hartlepool United", "Fulham", "Fleetwood Town", "Leyton Orient", "Huddersfield Town", "Gillingham",
                 "Luton Town", "Hull City", "Millwall", "Mansfield Town", "Ipswich Town", "Oldham Athletic",
                 "Morecambe", "Leeds United", "Peterborough United", "Newport County", "Middlesbrough", "Port Vale",
                 "Northampton Town", "Milton Keynes", "Notts County", "Nottingham Forest", "Scunthorpe United",
                 "Oxford United", "Preston North End", "Sheffield United", "Plymouth Argyle", "Queens Park Rangers",
                 "Shrewsbury Town", "Portsmouth", "Reading", "Southend", "United Stevenage", "Rotherham United",
                 "Swindon Town", "Wycombe Wanderers", "Sheffield Wednesday", "Walsall", "Yeovil Town",
                 "Wolverhampton Wanderers", "Wigan Athletic", "York City"]
        self.team_name = random.choice(names)


# controls the whole game, incorporates all functions and classes
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        rebel = True
        # creates the users team
        self.my_team = NewTeam()
        # allows user customisation of team name
        while rebel:
            self.my_team.team_name = input("What is your teams name? ")
            if len(self.my_team.team_name) >= 50:
                rebel = True
                print("Too many characters in your team name, please choose one with less than 50 characters - ")
            else:
                rebel = False
        # creating the other teams, using the NewTeam class
        self.team1 = NewTeam()
        self.team2 = NewTeam()
        self.team3 = NewTeam()
        self.team4 = NewTeam()
        self.team5 = NewTeam()
        self.team6 = NewTeam()
        self.team7 = NewTeam()
        self.team8 = NewTeam()
        self.team9 = NewTeam()
        # an array to hold all the other teams and keep it neat
        self.other_teams = [self.team1, self.team2, self.team3, self.team4, self.team5, self.team6, self.team7,
                            self.team8, self.team9]
        # variable to hold which teams will be facing each other, for later printing in one go
        self.matches = []

    def match(self):
        # creates the five different matches randomly
        teams = self.other_teams
        match1 = [self.my_team]
        match2 = []
        match3 = []
        match4 = []
        match5 = []
        random_team = random.choice(teams)
        teams.remove(random_team)
        match1.append(random_team)
        for i in range(2):
            random_team = random.choice(teams)
            teams.remove(random_team)
            match2.append(random_team)
        for i in range(2):
            random_team = random.choice(teams)
            teams.remove(random_team)
            match3.append(random_team)
        for i in range(2):
            random_team = random.choice(teams)
            teams.remove(random_team)
            match4.append(random_team)
        for i in range(2):
            random_team = random.choice(teams)
            teams.remove(random_team)
            match5.append(random_team)
        # resets the other teams variable as the teams where removed from before
        self.other_teams = [self.team1, self.team2, self.team3, self.team4, self.team5, self.team6, self.team7,
                            self.team8, self.team9]
        # assigns the list of matches
        self.matches = [match1, match2, match3, match4, match5]
        print("")
        print("")
        # prints who will be playing who
        for match in self.matches:
            print(match[0].team_name + " will be playing " + match[1].team_name)
            time.sleep(1)
        print("")
        print("")

    def process_turn(self):
        # if the player has upgrade points the game asks if they would like to upgrade their players
        while True:
            player_upgrade = input("Would you like to upgrade your players? Enter yes or no - ")
            if player_upgrade == "yes":
                self.upgrade_player()
                break
            if player_upgrade == "no":
                print("")
                print("")
                break
            else:
                print("That is not a valid input. Try again")
                print("")
        # the player can either start a new match or view the rankings of the teams
        print("Enter \"rankings\" to see the league tables")
        print("Enter \"new match\" to play the next match")
        while True:
            next_input = input("What would you like to do? ")
            if next_input == "rankings":
                self.rankings()
                break
            elif next_input == "new match":
                self.match()
                self.process_matches()
                for object in self.my_team.team:
                    object.training_number = 0
                break
            else:
                print("That is not a valid input... Try again")

    def rankings(self):
        print("")
        print("")
        # creates all the teams by adding your team to the other teams
        all_teams = [self.my_team] + self.other_teams
        # creates ranked_teams where the team name and the teams score are sorted into order
        ranked_teams = []
        for team in all_teams:
            ranked_teams.append((team.points, team.team_name))
        # sorts the scores into order
        ranked_teams = sorted(ranked_teams, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
        # fails to keep that order with secondary key sort
        # ranked_teams = sorted(ranked_teams, key=itemgetter(1))
        # prints the teams in order of their scores to create the table
        counter = 1
        for team in ranked_teams:
            print(team[1] + " is in " + str(counter) + " place with " + str(team[0]) + " points")
            counter += 1
        print("")
        print("")

    def upgrade_player(self):
        # prints the players and their score so you can see who to upgrade
        for player in self.my_team.team:
            print(player[0] + ": " + player[1].name + " has a rating of: " + str(player[1].rating))
        print("")
        print("")
        # loop so that all upgrade points may be used
        while True:
            # tells the player how many points they have left and asks which player they would like to upgrade
            print("Who would you like to upgrade?")
            upgrading_input = input("Enter player position to upgrade or type 'exit' to quit upgrading your players - ")
            print("")
            # each statement checks if a player has been selected for training
            # if they have then the score is copied of later use
            # then the player is trained
            # then the difference in score is printed
            # the amount of points available to use is decreased
            if upgrading_input == "goalkeeper1":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[0][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[0][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[0][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[0][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[0][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[0][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[0][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "defender1":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[1][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[1][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[1][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[1][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[1][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[1][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[1][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "defender2":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[2][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[2][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[2][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[2][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[1][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[2][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[0][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "defender3":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[3][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[3][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[3][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[3][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[3][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[3][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[3][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "defender4":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[4][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[4][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[4][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[4][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[4][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[4][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[4][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "midfielder1":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[5][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[5][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[5][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[5][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[5][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[5][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[5][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "midfielder2":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[6][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[6][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[6][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[6][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[6][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[6][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[6][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "midfielder3":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[7][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[7][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[7][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[7][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[7][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[7][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[7][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "midfielder4":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[8][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[8][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[8][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[8][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[8][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[8][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[8][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "attacker1":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[9][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[9][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[9][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[9][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[9][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[9][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[9][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")

            elif upgrading_input == "attacker2":
                prev_rating = self.my_team.team[10][1].rating
                self.my_team.team[10][1].train_player()
                print(self.my_team.team[10][0] + ": " + self.my_team.team[10][1].name + " had a rating of " +
                      str(prev_rating) + " and now has rating of " + str(self.my_team.team[10][1].rating))
                print(self.my_team.team[10][1].name + " has trained " + str(self.my_team.team[10][1].training_number) +
                      " time(s)")
            # if the input was exit then upgrading of players stops
            elif upgrading_input == "exit":
                print("quiting")
                break
            # if the input was incorrect then it asks the input again
            else:
                print("That was an incorrect input. Try again")
            print("")

    def process_matches(self):
        # for each match the game decides who wins based on player ratings
        for match in self.matches:
            # obtains the rating of the two teams
            rating1 = 0
            rating2 = 0
            for player in match[0].team:
                rating1 += player[1].rating
            for player in match[1].team:
                rating2 += player[1].rating
            rating1 += random.randint(-10, 10)
            rating2 += random.randint(-10, 10)
            draw = random.randint(1, 20)
            # compares the rating of the two teams
            if draw == 20:
                rating1 = rating2
            else:
                pass
            if rating1 == rating2:
                print(match[0].team_name + " has drew against " + match[1].team_name)
                match[0].points += 1
                match[1].points += 1
                match[0].upgrade_points += 1
                match[1].upgrade_points += 1

            elif rating1 > rating2:
                print(match[0].team_name + " has won against " + match[1].team_name)
                match[0].points += 3
                match[0].upgrade_points += 3

            elif rating2 > rating1:
                print(match[1].team_name + " has won against " + match[0].team_name)
                match[1].points += 3
                match[1].upgrade_points += 3
            time.sleep(1)
            """need to figure out how the next two lines work, namely, how does the instance have the
            training_number attribute yet i can't get hold of and then change it"""
            # for player in self.my_team.team:
            #     player.training_number = 0
        # the other teams players gets randomly upgraded if they have enough points
        for team in self.other_teams:
            for points in range(team.upgrade_points):
                player = random.choice(team.team)
                player[1].train_player()
                team.upgrade_points -= 1
        print("")
        print("")

game = Game()
while True:
    game.process_turn()

# I need to fix the training number, the class has a value of 0, but, the instances/players have their own value
# accrued which will hopefully be reset to 0 after each match played, but hard to do

# need a end game, a simple way of after 10 matches or something it ends season and starts again, your team stays the
# same all others are remade and randomised again
```

My problem lies with the idea of there being detrimental effects with over-training, the code for this is a mess and could probably be much more efficient while even I get confused sometimes, I have tried to make it so that after a match (equivalent to 1 week) the training number of all players resets to 0 so that they can train again... So I have checked that I can change the value in a singular case and have been able to do so but when I try to change the value shortly after the matches are played out in the function `process_turn(self)` it just doesn't seem to work, I've tried looking at many examples online and other questions on here but the closest I seem to have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245296/how-to-change-the-attributes-for-all-objects-inside-a-list-in-python3). Yet here I am stuck trying to tackle the for loop contained in this part...

```
while True:
            next_input = input("What would you like to do? ")
            if next_input == "rankings":
                self.rankings()
                break
            elif next_input == "new match":
                self.match()
                self.process_matches()
                **for object in self.my_team.team:
                    object.training_number = 0**
                break
            else:
                print("That is not a valid input... Try again")
```

Comment: Thanks @techraf, I did look at that and wonder what the heck happened

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code that reproduces your problem ?

Comment: Whats wrong with Your current code, it look reasonable? Also, If You want us to help You, You should provide a short runnable example of what You are trying to achieve because it's far too much code to go through...

Comment: The last part where it shows the part - for object in self.my_team.team          it produces an error as opposed to actually changing the players attribute

Comment: unfortunately @Johan Boule it incorporates most of the code, simply running the code and training someone shows that they have been trained once, then playing a match to change it and train a player again should show that yet again that they've only been trained once but it states that the players don't have the attribute training_number which they clearly do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your team property is of type: [string*NewPlayer]

You're iterating through the array and trying to set the training_number property on your tuple which just doesn't make sense.

You want to set the training_number property on the NewPlayer object inside the tuple, like follows. The problem is, tuples are immutable so you can't do this.

```
for object in self.my_team.team:
    object1[1].training_number = 0
```

Instead you could change your team to be a dictionary{string: NewPerson}

```
for role,person in self.my_team.team.iteritems():
    person.training_number = 0
```

And then in your team class you'd have to change your create_team function to use a dictionary instead of a list.

```
self.team = {}
self.team["goalkeeper1"] = NewPlayer()
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I do know that the code is disgusting but it was made with the intention of being used in a short time, I did see the problem with the string*NewPlayer but wasn't sure how I could make it a variable which could replace it all while being able to use the same function for the NPC's teams

Comment: Dude you are a legend